# Extract string from a column in mysql and replace in place

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql, there are two columns in this table 'ID' and 'Branch'. I want to make the fix the column 'Branch'

Structure:

```
ID    Branch
1     ?¤All-bank
2     (1) bank
3     ÂJohn & William
4     % Bank
5     ----Road one
6     ?bank
```

Output expected:

```
ID    Branch
1     All-bank
2     bank
3     John & William
4     Bank
5     Road one
6     bank
```

So basically the branch can contain english characters and some special characters like ".,/&-"

I was think on these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE branch like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

Can anyone help me on this, mysql newbie here.

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) to see if any of the answers helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped